# Cannot unserialize YAML columns with R: NAs introduced by coercion: 3.0 is out of real range

Tags: r, dplyr, yaml

I am using the yaml package with version 2.1.15, on R, trying to unserialize a column that was generated by a web app from YAML to a JSON format.

```
> tbl %>%
+   select(value) %>% 
+   collect() %>% 
+   head(20)
# A tibble: 20 x 1
                                                                       value
                                                                       <chr>
 1                                                                "--- []\n"
 2                                                                "--- []\n"
 3                     "---\n- - unknown\n  - 383.0\n- - hd720\n  - 425.0\n"
 4                                                                "--- []\n"
 5                                             "---\n- - hd720\n  - 102.0\n"
 6                                             "---\n- - unknown\n  - 0.0\n"
 7                                                                "--- []\n"
 8                      "---\n- - unknown\n  - 301.0\n- - hd1080\n  - 1.0\n"
 9                                                                "--- []\n"
10                                           "---\n- - hd1080\n  - 1103.0\n"
11                                                                "--- []\n"
12                                                                "--- []\n"
13                                            "---\n- - hd1080\n  - 803.0\n"
14                                             "---\n- - hd720\n  - 143.0\n"
15                                                                "--- []\n"
16                                                                "--- []\n"
17 "---\n- - unknown\n  - 9.0\n- - hd1080\n  - 102.0\n- - hd720\n  - 37.0\n"
18                                           "---\n- - unknown\n  - 136.0\n"
19                                             "---\n- - hd720\n  - 973.0\n"
20                      "---\n- - unknown\n  - 330.0\n- - hd1080\n  - 3.0\n"
```

I try to unserialize this column using the following function:

```
df = read.csv("test.txt")
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(
    unserialized_value = ifelse(
      is.recursive(yaml.load(value)) || is.vector(yaml.load(value)),
      as.character(toJSON(yaml.load(value))),
      as.character(yaml.load(value)))
  ) %>%
  View()
```

I've implemented the same as a function:

```
unserialize_value <- function(val) {
  if (length(val) != 1) {
    stop("unserialize_value input must be of length 1")
  }
  if (is.na(val)) {
    return(NA)
  } else {
    print(paste("orig val:", val))
    yaml_val = yaml.load(val)
    print(paste("YAML val:", yaml_val))
    if (is.recursive(yaml_val) || is.vector(yaml_val)) {
      print("returning list")
      return(as.character(toJSON(yaml_val)))
    } else {
      print("returning char")
      return(as.character(yaml_val))
    }
  }
}
```

When using this function in `mutate` (but also when using the inline code), I get output like this (debugging statements):

```
[1] "returning list"
[1] "orig val: ---\n- - hd720\n  - 973.0\n"
[1] "YAML val: list(\"hd720\", NA)"
[1] "returning list"
[1] "orig val: ---\n- - unknown\n  - 330.0\n- - hd1080\n  - 3.0\n"
[1] "YAML val: list(\"unknown\", NA)" "YAML val: list(\"hd1080\", NA)"
```

And indeed, the numbers have been turned into `NA`s, due to these errors:

```
1: In yaml.load(value) : NAs introduced by coercion: 301.0 is out of real range
2: In yaml.load(value) : NAs introduced by coercion: 1.0 is out of real range
3: In yaml.load(value) : NAs introduced by coercion: 301.0 is out of 
...
```

The file is here: [test.txt](https://github.com/viking/r-yaml/files/1551287/test.txt)

Interestingly enough, when I do:

```
toJSON(yaml.load("---\n- - unknown\n  - 330.0\n- - hd1080\n  - 3.0\n"))
```

It works fine:

```
[[["unknown"],[330]],[["hd1080"],[3]]]
```

Is there anything happening with the `dplyr` / `mutate` call that is messing up the conversion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran your code and it worked fine in all cases. I suspect there's a version difference in loaded libraries. Please include sessionInfo() output for comparison.

Here's mine:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/openblas-base/libblas.so.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/libopenblasp-r0.2.18.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] bindrcpp_0.2 dplyr_0.7.4  magrittr_1.5 yaml_2.1.15  jsonlite_1.5

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.4.3   assertthat_0.2.0 R6_2.2.2         tools_3.4.3      glue_1.2.0       tibble_1.3.4    
 [7] Rcpp_0.12.13     pkgconfig_2.0.1  rlang_0.1.2      bindr_0.1
```

====
Updated, the bug has been patched in the latest version of r-yaml. The root cause was additional error checking errno on conversions. Since this is a shared global in c stdlib, it can get set by anything using the c stdlib, in this case it was jsonlite using log10 on a numeric zero. This set errno, and got detected later as an error on conversion. The solution was to clear errno before using strtol or strtoi in the r-yaml package.

TL;DR install latest r-yaml from CRAN.

Comment: If you're spgarbet on GitHub, feel free to edit your post to point to the bug / bugfix!

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug with the YAML package, [fixed in the most recent release](https://github.com/viking/r-yaml/commit/a95b5f2022f98687ee63610d56285bc82f55ecae).